# Data Access best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have different Models in my Asp.Net Core application. Is it recommended to do `SQL` queries inside `IActionResult` Action methods? or is a better to have a seperate class do all work in terms of fetching data for each of the models and return the result to `IActionResult` method where we can display `Return View()`?
I have a static Utility class. If I were to have a class for each model to fetch data I would need access to `IHttpContextAccessor` but i cant assign that in a static class. What type of class would be the way to go?

Comment: As with a lot of things in software development... "it depends". Your missing a million things this depends on in your question.

Comment: In general though, What type of class is used to do SQL queries, read the data and put it into a model then return that model to the method that called it? I can do it with static classes but there are times that i need HttpContext to do the SQL query and i cant access that in a static class

Comment: Actually, for a small project, I recommend Entity Framerwork Core. Create a folder named Data, and scaffold your existing DataBase into that. Then you can use DependencyInjection to inject an instance of the Context into each controller, and then query your data using linq.

Comment: @Guilherme Can you tell me how it could be done without Ef? I feel like static classes aren't supposed to be used for fetching data

Comment: What exactly do you mean by static classes? Entity framework is a stateful based approach, with only instance classes (except a few static ones that add some extension methods to some stuff)

Comment: EF is the best way IMO. But if you want, I recommend creating a DLL project and hiding all the parametrized queries in there. Expose only methods like `List<Client> clients = await Clients.GetByIdAsync(50)`. Avoid query strings in the Controllers.

Comment: If you are using .NET Core/ASP.NET Core, then Entity Framework Core is actually the recommended way for data access. Take a look at this tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for the repository pattern (https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), adding a generic repository (one single class) or a concrete repository (one per model).
Another solution would be using partial classes, to add data access logic in your model classes.
In example:

```
public partial class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyModel
{
    //add data access here
}
```

Also to identify them, you could add an extension to model class files, like ".cs.da" (then you would have "MyModel.cs" and "MyModel.cs.da" files) and nest them using File nesting extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting

Comment: thanks for the help. What is the recommended pattern for a simple action like fetching user information from database? Should the method take a parameter and pull up that `UserID` or should it just take the `UserID` from `session` directly?

Comment: If you want to go with something like my 2nd approach, then you should use DAO or something like that (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object).  
Then, about your last question:  
The best practise is to make data access methods "business logic agnostic".  
That's because you dont want to couple it to the session object, so the best way is making the data access method take the userID, and not even knowing session object.  
Then you would wire things up inside Controller, there you get userID from session, and pass it to DAO object.